# Dockerfile doesn't seem to be exposing ports

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, port

I'm trying to run a simple node server on port `8080`, but with the following config any attempt at hitting the subdomain results in a `502 Bad Gateway` error. If I go the node I can see there doesn't appear to be any ports open on the container itself. So, assuming I've checked everything correctly, is there anything else I need to do in the config to open the port for the node server?

Edit: If I ssh into the pod and `curl` localhost on `8080` I'm able to hit the node server.

[image]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.18.1

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**k8s deployment**

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: test_image
    ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      containerPort: 8080
```

**service yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: test-deployment
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

**Ingress**

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Answer (score 3):

This wound up being on the application side. The server needed to be bound to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

[image]